# Using babel env with the plugin for template literals isn't working with Webpack

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the following configuration in my webpack

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        presets: ['env'],
        plugins: [require("babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals")]
    }
}
```

And I have the following in my package.json

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
```

But when I include the following template literal in my code `.attr("transform", "translate(0, ${staticHeightForNow} )")` it doesn't work and instead I get the following error on the frontend...

> Error:  attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "translate(0, ${staticHeightFo…".

What am I missing? How do I use Template Literals with Babel?

Answer (score 1):

Oops I was using double qoutes `"` instead of gravemarkers `